# Compress membership table

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, compression, encode

I have a huge table, containing the membership between elements and sets.

The row headers are element names, and the columns headers are set names. The value of each cell is true `1` or false `0`, which true means the element belongs to the set, false is otherwise.

For example:

```
   e1 e2 e3 e4 e5
s1  1  1  1  0  1
s2  0  1  0  1  0
s3  1  1  1  1  0
```

I can't send clients this huge table as they don't care about the full picture, but I need to give them the most compressed / encoded version so that they can use to quickly check whether some e belong to some s.

How can I construct such a compressed table?

Comment: You compress your table so that each element is stored in 1 bit, or you can provide a service for the client to make a query.

Comment: You should give more characteristic of the data to us. That way, maybe we can give algorithm that exploit it the best. Such as 'the rows are likely to be similar', 'many of the sets are subset/union of other sets', 'the matrix is sparse', or 'the sum of each column never exceed x'. Otherwise, we can only suggest that you pick one of the **generic** compression algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** If your table is filled most with cells with 1's, you could use a sparse table, sending only the 0's (or the opposite), or use a single bit to represent each of the cells.

**2.** Also, you can compress the data to be sent using Zlib or you can implement Huffman yourself, so you don't depend on external libraries.

**3.** If your client needs only a sub-set of the full table send just the subset.

Note that all of these techniques can be used together: technique 1 change your data structure; technique 2 changes the "encoding" of the data to be sent; technique 3 change the data that will be sent to client.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach:

For each and every set there will be string of zeros and ones based on the unavailability and availability of the elements respectively. Just convert that binary (String of zeros and ones) into decimal and save some space.

-Ashish